# How to define constructor outside the class in c#

Tags: c#, c++

I am new to c# and just switched from c++ to c#.
I was doing something like this in c++:

```
Class A
{
 public : A(char *argv);//declaration of constructor
}
```

then in main i was doing like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 A Obj(argv[1]);
}
```

then definition of constructor i do like this :

```
A::A(char * argv) 
{
 //Here i use this command line argument argv which contains a file.
}
```

I tried to write equivalent code in c# which is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace shekhar_final
 {
    class Huffman 
    {
    public  int data_size,length,i,is_there, total_nodes;
    string code;
    Huffman(char  *args);
    }

        public   Huffman(char  *args) //called from MyClass  Line:16
        {
            using (var stream = new BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(args[0])))  //Line : 18
            {
                while (stream.BaseStream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length)
                {
                    byte processingValue = stream.ReadByte();
                }
            }
        }

    public class MyClass 
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {       
         Huffman ObjSym =new Huffman(args);//object creation
        }
    }
}// Line:34
```

The couple of errors i got are ://**I have indicated the line corresponding to the errors in my code**

```
shekhar_c#.cs(16,25): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `Huffman', expecting `class', `delegate', `enum', `interface', `partial', or `struct'
shekhar_c#.cs(18,33): error CS1530: Keyword `new' is not allowed on namespace elements
shekhar_c#.cs(18,36): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `BinaryReader', expecting `class', `delegate', `enum', `interface', `partial', or `struct'
shekhar_c#.cs(18,79): warning CS0658: `value' is invalid attribute target. All attributes in this attribute section will be ignored
shekhar_c#.cs(34,1): error CS8025: Parsing error
Compilation failed: 4 error(s), 1 warnings
```

Could you please help me in writing c# equivalent of this c++ (removing these errors). Extra guidance are also welcome because i am beginner to c#.

Comment: C# does not use header files.  You define the constructor (and everything else for that matter) inside the class definition.

Comment: The only way to do that would be with a `partial` class, but really, don't.

Comment: Consider reading a book about c# rather than the direct translation from c++ to c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# requires constructors to be defined within the class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace shekhar_final
{
    public class Huffman{

    public  int data_size,length,i,is_there, total_nodes;
    string code;

     public   Huffman(string[]  args) //called from MyClass  Line:16
     {
         using (var stream = new BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(args[0])))  //Line : 18
         {
             while (stream.BaseStream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length)
             {
                 byte processingValue = stream.ReadByte();
             }
         }
      }
    }

   public class MyClass 
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {       
         Huffman ObjSym =new Huffman(args);//object creation
       }
   }
}// Line:34
```

Comment: I am passing the pointers in the c# if you see my constructor definition and call i read a binary file at terminal , Is it normal to do Huffman(char  *args) in c# as well,I mean use of this "*" ? because i am reading the file at terminal? If not then how to achieve the same ?

Comment: no, pointers are considered `unsafe`, you really don't need to do it that way.

Comment: i changed my constructor to what it should be for c#

Answer (score 3):

Unlike C++ where you have a choice of combining the declaration and the definition of a member function  in the header, or placing the declaration in the header and the implementation in the cpp file, in C# there is no such choice: if a function has a body (i.e. it is not abstract), the body needs to be part of the declaration:

```
class Huffman 
{
    public  int data_size,length,i,is_there, total_nodes;
    string code;
    Huffman(string args) {
        using (var stream = new BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(args)))
        {
            while (stream.BaseStream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                byte processingValue = stream.ReadByte();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C#, declarations and implementations go together:

```
namespace shekhar_final
{
    class Huffman 
    {
        public int DataSize {get; set;}
        public int Length {get; set;}
        public int I {get;set;}
        public int IsThere {get;set;}
        public int TotalNodes {get;set;}
        private string code;

        public Huffman(string[] args) //called from MyClass  Line:16
        {
            using (var stream = new BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(args[0])))  //Line : 18
            {
                while (stream.BaseStream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length)
                {
                    byte processingValue = stream.ReadByte();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyClass 
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {       
           Huffman objSym = new Huffman(args);//object creation
        }
    }
}// Line:34
```

Comment: I am passing the pointers in  the c# if you see my  command line argument , Is it normal to do in c# as well ? because i am reading the file at terminal?

Comment: No, you should almost never work with pointers in C# (it would require unsafe context).  I did not adapt answer for that.  You should use `string` to do strings.  Let me adapt my answer to make it a bit more C#... Stand by....

Answer (score 2):

You don't define methods ahead of time in C# - they're defined within the class itself. Try this instead:

```
class Huffman 
{
public  int data_size,length,i,is_there, total_nodes;
string code;

    public Huffman(char *args) //called from MyClass  Line:16
    {
        using (var stream = new BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(args[0])))  //Line : 18
        {
            while (stream.BaseStream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                byte processingValue = stream.ReadByte();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {       
         Huffman ObjSym =new Huffman(args); //Here is the error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but there is still one problem :I am passing the pointers in the c# if you see my constructor definition and call i read a binary file at terminal , Is it normal to do Huffman(char args) in c# as well,I mean use of this "" ? because i am reading the file at terminal? If not then how to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 2):

The main phlosophy between C# and C++ are different.  In C++ you have a header file and an implementation file.  In C#, everthing needs to be within a class.  So, you declare the constructor to the class and put the implementation within it.

```
class funny {
    public funny() {
     ...  add your constructor stuff here
    }
    ... other stuff ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks fo rthe answer but still there is a problem in the same code: I am passing the pointers in the c# if you see my constructor definition and call i read a binary file at terminal , Is it normal to do Huffman(char args) in c# as well,I mean use of this "" ? because i am reading the file at terminal? If not then how to achieve the same ?

Comment: Instead of using "" use String.Empty.  To use pointers within managed code, you need to mark that section as unmanaged.

Answer (score 1):

In c# you do not separate declaration and definition.  There is no such concept as declaration in c# since all the types exist together in an assembly. If you wish to use multiple files in c3 for classes you can use the concept of [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).